# how to use pandas groupby with itertools product

Tags: python, pandas, product, python-itertools

I have a df that outlines some lines and their respective parameters. The request is to create a df with combinations of the three parameters for each of the lines, that is line1 should have 8 combinations and line 2 should have another 8 combinations. The result df would have 16 rows.

Here is the df:

| line | param1 | param2 | param3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| line1 | 1abc | 1qwe | 1poi |
| line1 | 1bcd | 1ewq | 1iop |
| line2 | 2abc | 2qwe | 2poi |
| line2 | 2bcd | 2ewq | 2iop |

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df.groupby('line').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(data=list(product(df['param1'], df['param2'],df['param3'])), columns=['param1','param2','param3'])).reset_index()
```

I can't get the groupby to work. the above creates total parameter combinations for both line1 and line2, so it is creating 128 lines in total as opposed to 16.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `df` in your `apply` function but `x` (and don't forget to use `droplevel(1)` before `reset_index()`):

```
out = df.groupby('line').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(data=list(product(x['param1'], x['param2'],x['param3'])), columns=['param1','param2','param3'])).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     line param1 param2 param3
0   line1   1abc   1qwe   1poi
1   line1   1abc   1qwe   1iop
2   line1   1abc   1ewq   1poi
3   line1   1abc   1ewq   1iop
4   line1   1bcd   1qwe   1poi
5   line1   1bcd   1qwe   1iop
6   line1   1bcd   1ewq   1poi
7   line1   1bcd   1ewq   1iop
8   line2   2abc   2qwe   2poi
9   line2   2abc   2qwe   2iop
10  line2   2abc   2ewq   2poi
11  line2   2abc   2ewq   2iop
12  line2   2bcd   2qwe   2poi
13  line2   2bcd   2qwe   2iop
14  line2   2bcd   2ewq   2poi
15  line2   2bcd   2ewq   2iop
```